# How to loop through Rows of filtered ListObject using the .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible) property

Tags: excel, vba, listobject

I have a table of data with 5 columns.  I am using a ListObject to filter data in a table based on some criteria.  I would like to loop through each row of the filtered data to pick out data from 2 columns to use them to populate a list box on a form.  I can't find a way to loop through each row of the range referenced using the SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible) property.  I can loop through every cell in the range but I only need data from the 2nd and 3rd column.  I can use a counter to do this but it seems a bit clunky as in the example below.  Is there another way to reference SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible) to do this more efficiently?

```
Public Sub PopulateListBox()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim lstObj As ListObject
    Dim rngResults As Range
    Dim strFilter As String
    Dim intCount As Integer
    Dim strLocation As String
    Dim strTelNo As String
    
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Location Data")
    Set lstObj = ws.ListObjects(1)
    
    If lstObj.ShowAutoFilter Then
        lstObj.ShowAutoFilter = False
    End If
    
    'Filter the list by the name of an option on Form.  
    'Simplified the code here so the Form isn't 'required.
    
    'strFilter = tsRegion.SelectedItem.Caption   'Requires the UserForm to run so hardcoded here.

    strFilter = "North East"                     'to "North East" for this example.
    
    With lstObj.Range 'Filter by the filter value selected on the form.
        .AutoFilter Field:=5, Criteria1:=strFilter
    End With
    
    'Loop through all 5 columns in the table and add the values of the 2 columns 
    'needed as an entry on a list box on a userform
    intCount = 1
    For Each rngResults In lstObj.DataBodyRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
        '########################################
        'This 'works' but feels really clunky.
        'Ideally would a way to loop through all visible rows, not individual cells
        'It also needs a tweak to skipped the header row
        '########################################
        
        Select Case intCount
            Case 2 'data from 2nd column of table
                strLocation = rngResults.Value
            Case 3 'data from 3rd column of table
                strTelNo = rngResults.Value
            Case 5
              'Commented out the code below for this example as it is populating
              'a listbox on a UserForm. It works but simplified for this example.
              'Changed it to output to the debug window instead.
              ' With Me.lstBox   'A list box on a UserForm.
                  '  .AddItem
                  '  .List(intRowCount, 0) = strLocation
                   ' .List(intRowCount, 1) = strTelNo
              ' End With
              Debug.Print strLocation, strTelNo
              intCount = 0
        End Select
        intCount = intCount + 1
    Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

### Copy Excel Table Filtered Data to Listbox

[image]

```
Sub PopulateListBox()
    
    Const SHEET_NAME As String = "Location Data"
    Const TABLE_ID As Variant = 1 ' or e.g. "Table1" ('As Variant')
    Const FILTER_COLUMN As Long = 5
    Const COLUMN_WIDTHS As String = "75;75" ' adjust!
    Dim CopyColumns() As Variant: CopyColumns = Array(2, 3)
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(SHEET_NAME)
    Dim lo As ListObject: Set lo = ws.ListObjects(TABLE_ID)
    
    Dim CriteriaString As String: CriteriaString = "North East"
'    Dim CriteriaString As String:
'    CriteriaString =  tsRegion.SelectedItem.Caption
    
    If lo.ShowAutoFilter Then
        If lo.AutoFilter.FilterMode Then lo.AutoFilter.ShowAllData
    End If
        
    Dim vrg As Range, AreVisibleCellsFound As Boolean
        
    lo.Range.AutoFilter Field:=FILTER_COLUMN, Criteria1:=CriteriaString
    On Error Resume Next
        Set vrg = lo.DataBodyRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    On Error GoTo 0
    lo.AutoFilter.ShowAllData
        
    If vrg Is Nothing Then
        GoTo CopyToListbox
    Else
        AreVisibleCellsFound = True
    End If
    
    Dim rCount As Long: rCount = Intersect(lo.Range.Columns(1), vrg).Cells.Count
    Dim cCount As Long: cCount = UBound(CopyColumns) - LBound(CopyColumns) + 1
    Dim Data() As Variant: ReDim Data(1 To rCount, 1 To cCount)
    
    Dim arg As Range, rrg As Range, CopyColumn As Variant
    Dim r As Long, c As Long

    For Each arg In vrg.Areas
        For Each rrg In arg.Rows
            r = r + 1
            c = 0
            For Each CopyColumn In CopyColumns
                c = c + 1
                Data(r, c) = rrg.Cells(CopyColumn).Value
            Next CopyColumn
        Next rrg
    Next arg
    
CopyToListbox:
            
    If AreVisibleCellsFound Then
        With lo.DataBodyRange
            .Resize(rCount, cCount).Offset(, .Columns.Count + 1).Value = Data
        End With
'        With Me.lstBox
'            .ColumnCount = cCount
'            .ColumnWidths = COLUMN_WIDTHS
'            .List = Data
'        End With
        MsgBox "List box populated.", vbInformation
    Else
'        Me.lstBox.Clear
        MsgBox "No filtered data found!", vbExclamation
    End If
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I can see you've put a lot of effort into finding a solution.  Isn't this getting the same result but via a different approach? Instead of looping through all cells of the filtered dataset and adding them row by row to the listbox, it seems like adding it to an array first and then adding that to the listbox in one go?

Comment: Also, found a different way to check if the filtered list has no results without generating an error by counting the number of items in one column.  It will contain 1 item only (the column header) if the filtered list is empty.  If its bigger than 1 then there should be some results: 
##  If lo.Range.Columns(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Count > 1  ##.

I can see you trap for the error which also works:
On Error Resume Next
        Set vrg = lo.DataBodyRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
On Error GoTo 0

Answer (score 0):

Accordingly with your explanation, I tkink you're just want to loop trough the "row" objects. So, you can loop them this way:

```
For Each rngResults In lstObj.DataBodyRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Rows
```

And your `rngResults` variable will represent a row on each iteration. Based on that, then you can get the n-column value, accessing it from "Columns" method:

```
strLocation = rngResults.Columns(2)
strTelNo = rngResults.Columns(3)
```

Comment: Thanks, your answer totally makes sense however the resulting range (rngResults) from using .rows is always 1.  ie lstObj.DataBodyRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Rows.Count always = 1.  This is odd as if i check the number of rows in the base LIstObject it will be the correct number of unfilters rows ie lstObj.range.Rows.Count and if I check in the actual sheet there is more than one row returned when filtered.  Is it because the range returned by .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible) is a collection of resulting cells and not actually a table like structure?